# add custom view to window and blur the background view and not allow to click background view

Tags: iphone, ios

hello ，i custom a view 290*280 like a dialog,all is ok,but other view of behind my custom view can click,i want to the other view can click when my customView pop,i also want to the window of behind my custom view is blur.

my code is :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RecordView :UIView


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *confirmBu;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *playBu;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *recrodBu;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *closeBu;


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *backgroundImageview;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *showImageview;

-(void)setViewStyle;
@end

 #import "RecordView.h"

    @interface RecordView ()

    @end

    @implementation RecordView

    @synthesize confirmBu;
    @synthesize playBu;
    @synthesize recrodBu;
    @synthesize closeBu;



    @synthesize backgroundImageview;
    @synthesize showImageview;



    -(void)setViewStyle{

         self.frame=CGRectMake(15,100, 290, 280);
         self.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

        backgroundImageview.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
        backgroundImageview.layer.cornerRadius=15.0;
        backgroundImageview.layer.borderWidth=4.0;
        backgroundImageview.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor];

    }

    @end

self.recordDialog= [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RecordView" owner:self options:nil]lastObject];
                [self.recordDialog setViewStyle];
  [delegate.window addSubview:self.recordDialog];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way way of doing it is to programatically create a screenshot of the current screen. Blur the screenshot using something like https://github.com/tomsoft1/StackBluriOS and then set that image as the background. When you click on the close button all you have to do is hide the background image again.

Answer (score 0):

You can create semi transparent image which will give blur effect. Present first image and then 290*280 view over image. Image will prevent tapping on background control and you will have that blur look.

Comment: can you see more detail,i cannot understand